# Why Chinese subtitles in American shows are relatively simple?

Tags: translation, movies

Every time I watch an English show with Chinese subtitles, it's so much easier to read the subtitles than in a Chinese show.

What do you think is the reason for it?
Who does the translations?
Can you recommend a good site the offers shows with Chinese subtitles?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the characteristic of the "subtitle community".

Historically, before American (or western, but mostly American) shows are widely legally imported to China, the Chinese audience pretty much relied on piracy as their only source.

The subtitles of those, are of course contributed by the community, which, by its origin, is of "various" quality. This is still the case now because some publishers would purchase subtitles from the community and pair it with legally imported shows.

So, to directly answer your question: because most of the time they are not created by professionals.

Answer (score 2):

先问是不是，再问为什么。

I never feel Chinese subtitles in American shows are much easier than those in Chinese shows. I never hear any fellow Chinese say they feel the same way as OP.

If the OP feels this way, it's probably because OP is a English native speaker and can understand the content by hearing. Once you understand the content, it's mush easier for you to understand the subtitle. You could try watch a American show dubbed in Chinese and see if that feels easy, too.